# Multiple Box Plots in a single chart using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a set [data of gold price for the last 10 days](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7x4BoOdwK8TTVN0amY0Y01CNGc/view?usp=sharing) and I want to plot the data in form of candlesticks chart like this:

[image]

but instead of using candlesticks, I want to represent the data each day using [box plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot), for example
[image]

or like [this video](https://youtu.be/DrY50sH3SIE).

I want to use the following criteria in my new chart: x-axis is trading day and y-axis is gold price. So to speak, there will be 10 box plots in a single chart using the above data. My question is, what is the VBA program to create chart like that? I am new in VBA programming and I have tried to google this subject but nothing helps. Could someone here help me out? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The box (and whisker) plot is very poorly supported in Excel.  You can follow a tutorial to make one of these and then automate that tutorial with VBA.  [Here is one approach from Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/).  I link there because he offers an Excel add-in which will generate these.  You could make your own, I suspect it is difficult (especially for a beginner) but doable depending on how configurable you need it to be.  Getting 10 of these is not difficult once you get the first one.

Comment: @Byron Thanks for the info, very helpful. Appreciate it :)